# Loading Promise in Handlebars templates based on volatile computed property

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm building an asynchronous component for a sidebar that lists people you may know, a result set from an API.

The code below works to add these items to the page as they become available to the store. When the user logs out, I call `unloadAll()`, however, my `recommendations` computed property is `volatile()` so it's not cached and will populate with new entries for the next user (or the same) that logs into the application instance.

```
// app/services/invite.js

recommendations: Ember.computed(function() {
  return this.get('store').findAll('recommendation');
}).volatile(),

// app/templates/components/people-you-may-know.hbs

{{#each invite.recommendations as |person|}}
  {{...}}
{{/each}}

// app/components/people-you-may-know.js

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  invite: Ember.inject.service()
})
```

I think I need a new computed property like below, but this is where I'm struggling with blank pages and infinite loops.

```
reducedRecommendations: Ember.computed('recommendations', function()
  return this.get("recommendations").slice(0, 10);
}),

{{#each invite.reducedRecommendations as |person|}}
  {{...}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.get('store').findAll('recommendation')
```

This will return live arrays, which means whenever store is updated with new value then it will be updated automatically. so always it will be sync with store.
In that case you dont require `volatile` computed property.

```
recommendations: Ember.computed(function() {
  return this.get('store').findAll('recommendation');
}).volatile(),

reducedRecommendations: Ember.computed('recommendations', function()
  return this.get("recommendations").slice(0, 10);
}),
```

In the above code, `reducedRecommendations` - As this is requesting `recommendations` and it's changing `recommendations` property then again it will call `reducedRecommendations` this infinite loop will get started. since you are forcing to recompute `recommendations` trough `vloatile`.
If you just remove `volatile` and change dependence key to `recommendations.[]` will work seamless.

```
recommendations: Ember.computed(function() {
      return this.get('store').findAll('recommendation');
    })

reducedRecommendations: Ember.computed('recommendations.[]', function()
  return this.get("recommendations").slice(0, 10);
}),
```

Comment: Hi kumkanillam, the only issue with this so far is that `unloadAll` is not triggering changes on the `recommendations.[]` key as far as I can tell.

Comment: `reducedRecommendations` computed property will be called when you call `unloadAll`..you can play with this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/6b3e58ba0c8f1337c34c6f0b41a9d287?openFiles=services.invite.js%2C)

Comment: That twiddle is great. Thanks for creating that! I played around with it and got it to work as we've been expecting but the issue seems to be surrounding the fact that my application has no such `addOneEntry` action; we aren't pushing things into the store manually (but we are removing them manually via `unloadAll`). We're expecting the component to fetch new results. `unloadAll` is called from a logout action.

Comment: Does the `recommendations.[]` dependent key work with `unloadAll`? Yes. But then how to ensure new recommendations are added when a new user logs in or restore the previous ones if the same user logs in again. Does that make sense?

Comment: Either you can have `userLoginStaus` as dependant key for `recommendations` computed property. or you can define computed property with getters and setters and you can call setters after user is logged in. Modified the same [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/6b3e58ba0c8f1337c34c6f0b41a9d287?openFiles=services.invite.js%2C) with login/logout . login will load store and logout will unload store.

Comment: I can't really use `userLoginStaus` as a dependent key since the component won't be viewed when the user isn't logged in. Therefore, it will always show as `true` when the property itself is referenced. Using set is an interesting idea upon login but this is inefficient since not all logins will use this service and component. Maybe some combination of the two might work?

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` is not related to session cache. `volatile` caching means that computed property is not going to be cached and you need to get that to be calculated.

So I think you don't need to `volatile` and in `recommendation` CP just do your logic for current user and return the result.